# What is wrong with sql query

Tags: sql

What is wrong with this sql query. I am getting syntax error near convert

```
"SELECT * FROM collections c where c.submittedBy='679' AND CONVERT(varchar, c.eventTime, 103) ='2017-06-21'";
```

The eventTime is  "eventTime": "2017-06-21T12:20:03.9366135+05:30"

The error is

```
{"Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":64,\"end\":71},\"code\":\"SC1001\",\"message\":\"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'CONVERT'.\"}]}\r\nActivityId: a0c51c53-fca0-4c81-8f10-65348749e3d2"}
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: varchar needs a length specification ex: `varchar(100)`... but why are you converting dates to varchar?

Comment: cast or convert? what are you trying to use there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to write this query (across databases) is:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM collections c 
WHERE c.submittedBy='679' AND 
      c.eventTime >= '2017-06-21' AND
      c.eventTime < '2017-06-22';
```

This allows the database to use an appropriate index for filtering.  Note that if `submittedBy` is a number, then don't use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

convert to date before to convert to varchar

```
SELECT * 
FROM collections c 
where c.submittedBy='679' 
AND CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(date, c.eventTime, 103)) = '2017-06-21'
```

if eventTime is already a datetime field should work also this way..

```
SELECT * 
FROM collections c 
where c.submittedBy='679' 
AND CONVERT(date, c.eventTime) = '2017-06-21'
```